# call model function from another model in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, scope

how to call model method in another model, example
I have code like this

**/model/user.php**

```
public function get_token_by_id($id){
    //some code
}
```

i want call in my another model

**/model/restaurant**

```
App::bind('user','user');

class RestaurantController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct(user $modelUser){
        $this->modelUser = $modelUser;  
    }
    public function getUser(){
       $someVar = $this->modelUser->get_token_by_id($id);  
    }
}
```

But i get an error

**Call to a member function get_token_by_id() on a non-object**

how to fix it?

Comment: maybe `App::bind('user','User');` or `App::bind('user','App\User');`

Answer (score 1):

Well... that's because `$this->modelUser` is a non object !

To be more precise, `$this->modelUser` returns `null` or something like that (try a `var_dump($this->modelUser)`). It could be because your model doesn't have the attribute declaration (`protected $modelUser`) or because you don't pass the right variable into the constructor.

Comment: or in another words do something like this: $user = new User(); $someVar = $user->get_token_by_id($id);